# Why can't my program delete the files it creates under Win7?

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-7

I've made a Java program in Eclipse. I started on Windows XP, but have recently upgraded.

As part of it's saving mechanism, the program writes the settings to a file `settings_new.sav`. If that goes ok, it deletes the `settings.sav`, and renames the new one to match the old name. While it worked under winXP (at least I thought it did, but I can't check now), under win7, it fails to delete the file, even though it was the program that created it (although, a different instance of the program).

The file is picked up by Eclipse and can be deleted from there quite happily. I can delete it manually. I am the admin on my own computer. The folder is just inside the workspace folder, and is not in Program Files (though, I have no idea if eventual users will install it there). The program can create and modify files just fine. It's not throwing any Exception, which I thought it would if it was win7 blocking it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is due to file-locking mechanism in java.Make sure you close the buffering streams such as BufferedReader, BufferedInputStream on that file when done.

Comment: It's actually the file locking mechanisms in Windows.  The same code would likely work just fine under Linux.  But I agree, you should explicitly close access to the file to make it work properly everywhere.

Comment: @MarkRobinson:Interesting, I should test my swing applications in linux too.It seems that developers should anticipate problems at OS level rather than on JVM.

Comment: Windows and Linux have different file locking semantics.  Linux will allow you to delete a file you have open for editing without blowing up.  You can then create a new file with the same name without an issue.  In Windows, it can prevent you from deleting a file if it is open in another process.  The specific situations this happens depend greatly on how it is opened (by method/and access type).  If you have more questions I suggest you post a new SO question aimed at the Windows guys :)

Comment: So, I was thinking "Of course I closed it! I wouldn't make a stupid mistake like that for so long I have to ask on SO". Looked at all other alternatives I could think of. Nothing. Looked at the reader. It lacked a reader.close(); -_- *Headdesk* Thanks. But yeah, only on Win7, not WinXP. Interesting.

Answer (score -4):

I used to have this problem, when you are done using your file you have to set your file equal to null. So if you do something like:

```
public void createFile(String path)
{
    File file = new File(path);
    file.createNewFile();
    file = null
}
```

you have to set the file to null when you are done using it so that the system stops using that file. you have to do the same thing with FileReader and FileWriter. you have to set your file readers and your file writers to null in order to access the file again. Give this a try and let me know how it goes.

Comment: That's not going to work.  All that will do is allow the Java garbage collector to pick it up later.  Later being undefined.  You should explicitly close access to the file instead of waiting for the garbage collector to get it.

Comment: thats what setting it to null does, when you set something to null java automatically garbage collects.

Comment: It means that it is available for collection, not that collection happens instantly.  It could, but it is very JVM specific behavior.

Comment: Another reason that it won't work / won't make any difference is that the `File` object is not associated with any file locks/locking.  The file locking on Windows is associated with Java file streams or channels.  In short, it doesn't matter when the `File` object is garbage collected.